# Calcite and Avatica to expose a data warehouse as a virtual database

Tags: virtualization, apache-calcite

I have a question regarding the Calcite and Avatica libraries. We have a data warehouse, and I want to expose only selected tables from the DW and create a virtual database. My aim is to allow the consumer to query these tables via the JDBC driver. I came across the Calcite and Avatica libraries [Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/) and [Avatica](https://calcite.apache.org/avatica/), and they seem to be capable of doing this. Additionally, I want to expose specific columns from the tables and rename them if required.

However, I am facing difficulty in understanding these two libraries.
Can you please explain the functions of Calcite and Avatica? I intend to run this virtualization layer as a server on Kubernetes (maybe AWS or GCP) and create a JDBC driver that the consumer can download to query this virtual database.

I was able to connect to the Datawarehouse database and expose all the tables and columns using Avatica running as a server. However, I couldn't find a way to expose only certain tables and their columns. Can you provide some examples of how to do this? It seems like I need to override one of the Meta interfaces/classes.

Lastly, I am unsure which library to use to create a JDBC driver for the consumer of this virtual DB. Should I use Avatica or Calcite?